# What is the least element of this set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

What is the least element of the set

$$A=\{a\in \mathbb{R} \,\,| \,\,1<a<2\}        $$?

Is incorrect to write $$1,000...1 $$?

Comment: Not every set has a minimum, this is one such instance.

Comment: Does $\Re$ mean $\mathbb{R}$ here? If so, the set has no least element.

Comment: If you are asked to find the infimum which is the greatest lower bound then you want $a=1$. But $a=1$ is not in the set so it is not the minimum. Given your wording it appears you want to find the minimum, which does not exist here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open interval $(1,2)$ has no least element.  For every element $a \in (1,2)$ there is an element $b \in (1,2)$ with $b< a$; for example, the point $b = (1+a)/2$ that is halfway between $1$ and $a$.

It is meaningless to denote a real number via its decimal expansion as $1.000\ldots 1$. A decimal expansion has a first digit, a second digit, and more generally an $n$-th digit for every natural number $n$, but that's all.  It doesn't have any $\infty^{\text{th}}$ digit, whatever that might mean.

Comment: Beautiful answer. But, it is wrong to represent the least element as $$1,000...1$$?

Comment: @Voyager I edited; does it answer your second question now?

Comment: @Voyager, yes, it is wrong to write this as the least element. For example, 1,000...01 is smaller.

Comment: @JeremyUpsal That is true if the "$\ldots$" denotes only finitely many omitted digits.  I was assuming it denoted infinitely many omitted digits, in which case your expression (as well as the OPs) is meaningless.  Although if the OPs expression _were_ meaningfull, perhaps yours would be as well, but now we're getting into philosophy :-)

Comment: @TrevorWilson yes i got it, thank you very much

Comment: @JeremyUpsal i didn't thought about it! :)

Comment: @Voyager You're welcome.